Elastic Beanstalk nginx doesnt pass through request with spaces in URL
Im having an issue where i have requests to my backend that might contain encoded spaces, example:
GET /searchjob/word1%20word2
They arrive at the nginx in the ElasticBeanstalk instance where the backend is hosted, but are then not passed to my application. In the nginx/error.log i have the following logs:
2024/06/26 12:55:31 [warn] 8280#8280: *1575 using uninitialized "year" variable while logging request, client: 3.71.120.241, server: , request: "GET /searchjob/word1 word2 HTTP/1.1"
2024/06/26 12:55:31 [warn] 8280#8280: *1575 using uninitialized "month" variable while logging request, client: 3.71.120.241, server: , request: "GET /searchjob/word1 word2 HTTP/1.1"
2024/06/26 12:55:31 [warn] 8280#8280: *1575 using uninitialized "day" variable while logging request, client: 3.71.120.241, server: , request: "GET /searchjob/word1 word2 HTTP/1.1"
2024/06/26 12:55:31 [warn] 8280#8280: *1575 using uninitialized "hour" variable while logging request, client: 3.71.120.241, server: , request: "GET /searchjob/word1 word2 HTTP/1.1"

The caller then receives a 400 Bad Request, instead of the processed result.
I have not overwritten, or modified the nginx configuration in any way.
Any idea how to handle this?
